# How to detect keypress in python using keyboard module?

Tags: python, keyboard, keypress, detect

**I am making a program in python to detect what key is pressed and based on my keyboard it will make a decision.**

I want to implement it using  keyboard module in python.

I would do something like this,

```
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == 'enter':
        print('Enter is pressed)
    if keyboard.read_key() == 'q':
        print('Quitting the program)
        break
    if keyboard.read_key() == 's':
        print('Skiping the things')
```

***But it doesn't work. When I execute this program, I have to press **s**  twice to execute the **"s"** block.***

Also, I have a problem that is after the execution is finished, it writes all the keys in my command prompt is it possible to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Keyboard documentation](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/):

> Other applications, such as some games, may register hooks that    swallow all key events. In this case keyboard will be unable to    report events.

One way to solve your problem with `keyboard` module is `keyboard.wait('key')`

```
# Blocks until you press esc
keyboard.wait('esc')
```

Something work around is as below:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.wait('enter')
print('Enter is pressed')

keyboard.wait('q')
print('Quitting the program')

keyboard.wait('s')
print('Skiping the things')
```

Answer (score 0):

As Far I Know There is only one efficient  way to Detect user input weather it keybored or mouse input Which is library  called pynput ......

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key , Listener , Controller

keyboard = Controller()

DoubleShot=False
shot=False
def on_press(key):
    global  DoubleShot
    global  shot

    if Key.num_lock == key:
        print("activate")
        DoubleShot=True
    if DoubleShot:
        if Key.shift == key:
      
            shot = not shot
            if shot:
                keyboard.press(Key.shift)
                keyboard.release(Key.shift)

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press , on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

i create this  for a  game to shoot multiple  time on 'shift' clicked

- code activate only when  ' numlock ' clicked.....
- Controller is for clicking any key you want

Note:
In My case infinity looping was a problem that's why **shot** variable  is there to stop looping

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you forgot to close the strings on lines 4 and 6.

But your main issue is that you call `keyboard.read_key()` once for each arm of your if statement. This makes your code wait for a keypress, check if it's `'enter'`, then wait for another keypress, check if it's `'q'`, and so on.

What you should do is save the key to a variable, then check the variable. It should look something like this:

```py
import keyboard
while True:
    key = keyboard.read_key()
    if key == 'enter':
        print('Enter is pressed')
    if key == 'q':
        print('Quitting the program')
        break
    if key == 's':
        print('Skiping the things')
```